# ClassNotFoundException: com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTCreationException with DocuSignApi Java SDK

Tags: java, maven, jwt, docusignapi

I'm trying to implement some basic functionality with the newest DocuSignApi for Java (version 2.6.2).  I'm currently just trying to get the JWT Authorization Flow working.  Here's the code:

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();

this.apiClient.configureJWTAuthorizationFlow(this.adminProperties.getRsaPublicKey(), this.adminProperties
            .getRsaPrivateKey(), this.adminProperties.getoAuthBaseUrl(), this.adminProperties.getIntegratorKey(),
            this.adminProperties.getImpersonatedUserGuid(), TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS);
```

On the `ApiClient.configureJWTAuthorizationFlow(...) call above I'm receiving the following runtime error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTCreationException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I do not receive any compilation errors, just to be clear.

I have added this to my project pom as indicated from the [DocuSignApi Java Wiki](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client):

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.docusign</groupId>
    <artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Now I'm also using a Maven archetype that is pulling in a ton of other jars that are used with all of my company's projects and are needed for other functionality in my application.  I can see that my effective pom is pulling in this version of java-jwt & spring-security-jwt:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

I also noticed that one of the dependencies listed on the [DocuSignApi Java Wiki](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client) is as such:

```
org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.2
```

I suspect that my error may have something to do with a version conflict between the JWT 2.2.0 in my archetype and the required 1.0.2 version from DocuSign.

My questions are

1. Is my error indeed caused by a version conflict with the JWT jar?
2. If so, what's the best way to remedy this problem?  Can the DocuSignApi work with a newer version of JWT like I have?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here ended up being conflicting versions of the [java-jwt jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt).  My project is using the 2.2.0 version, but the dependency needed for the 2.6.2 version of the [Java DocuSign API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java/2.6.2) is 3.2.0.

The

```
org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.2
```

dependency I listed above was a misnomer...that wasn't the conflicting jar.

Since I do not have the ability to upgrade to the java-jwt 3.2.0 jar at this time I am forced to downgrade my Java DocuSign API to 2.2.1 where the dependency on the java-jwt is non-existent.

Hopefully someone else can benefit from the rather simple mistake I made here.